# XAMARIN ANDROID app got System.ServiceModel.FaultException

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have an app running well, but after I upgrade visual studio 2019 OSX, I got the exception when running the app.

Target _ResolveSatellitePaths:
    No way to resolve conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
Target _CopyConfigFiles:

[mono] Unhandled Exception:

[mono] System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Unable to load file or assembly 'DeepCloner, Version=0.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=dc0b95cf99bf4e99' Or one of its dependencies。 The definition of the found component information list does not match the component reference。 (An exception occurred on HRESULT: 0x80131040)

[mono-rt] [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Unable to load file or assembly'DeepCloner, Version=0.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=dc0b95cf99bf4e99' Or one of its dependencies。 The definition of the found component information list does not match the component reference。 (An exception occurred on HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I knew it's a dll conflict issue. but I can't find a way to fix it. thanks for any information.

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with updating [DeepCloner](https://github.com/force-net/DeepCloner/releases) to the latest verson `0.10.2`to check whether solve this .

> In this release we're removed System.Reflection namespace from
>   cloning, because some classes in System.Reflection.Emit cause
>   unexpected crashes in runtime. Also, there are no significant reasons
>   to clone these classes.
>
> Also, checking for empty constructors is improved to reduce number of
>   exceptions (internally catched, but can slow down copying).

Comment: use nuget to add deepcloner 0.10.2. but the exception still happen. even use deepcloner 10.0. still show unable to load.

Comment: @KenChu If so , need to connect nuget publisher to check this problem .